# Do ordnance drops need a path to the sky to work?

Tags: halo-4

I am creating a forge map on HALO 4. It is made for 4v4, and I know I need ordnance drops on the map for it to work in HALO 4's Community Forge Tester playlist (I think). I am using the map IMPACT, and I am creating a space station with no way in or out from the outside to remove the fact of using safe and kill zones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you don't need a path to the sky.  You can call ordnance drops from indoors just fine.  Instead of flying in like a drop pod, they just materialize out of thin air.

Comment: It looks to me that they're teleported in, they have a similar effect.

Comment: @rsegal, isn't teleportation materializing out of thin air?  :P

Comment: "Materializing out of thin air" has this whimsical handwaviness that we could, gosh, never have in _Halo_. That would be wrong.